# Conditional statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I need to write a conditional statement in my where clause that uses different operators based on the parameter passed into the procedure.  I can't seem to find the syntax that will work.

My example is as follows:

```
@DateValue datetime

select * 
from table
where field1 = 'x'
and field2 = 'y'
and if @DateValue = '1/1/1900' then
  field3 <= getdate()
else
  field3 = @DateValue
end
```

Thanks for everyone's assistance.

Comment: What is the context? Where does this SQL statement live?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
and ((@DateValue = '1/1/1900' and field3 <= getdate()) or 
     (@DateValue <> '1/1/1900' and field3=@DateValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need something like (psuedo-code)

```
Create PROCEDURE GetPartialTable
@DateValue datetime
   AS
Begin

IF (@DateValue = '1900-01-01') 
select * from table where field1 = 'x' and field2 = 'y'  and field3 <= getdate();
else
  select * from table where field1 = 'x' and field2 = 'y'  and field3 = @DateValue;
END IF

END
```

It sounds like the solution above, but the results might be seriously different if the context is more general, e.g. if the entire SQL statement is completely different.